Grafana + PromQL Join two metrics at one query
I am trying to create PromQL query which is representation of two metrics.
First metric
sum(machine_cpu_cores)
Second metric
sum(machine_memory_bytes)
How to create one PromQL query to achieve that?
My idea is to have that in Grafana Dashboard as:
Cluster 1 | sumCPU | sumRAM |
Cluster 2 | sumCPU | sumRAM |
Cluster 3 | sumCPU | sumRAM |
I have tried with group_left option but with no luck.
I have tried with some Grafana Transformation but with no luck.
I expect that two metrics will be one PromQL query.
